# facebook api 2.4, user_group permission

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-apps, usergroups

i have make a web site that required user_group permission, but when i decided to Publish it, i submit my apps for the review, i have discovered that user_group permission could not be approved.
[image]

But my website need to get the user groups list, how can i do it?

i have tryed using FQL or GRAPH API with 'user_managed_groups' permission but in the response there are only the groups were i am admin.

Help me, and sorry for my grammar :).

Answer (score 4):

> the `user_groups` permission has been deprecated. Developers may
>   continue to use the `user_managed_groups` permission to access the
>   groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still
>   accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available
>   in v2.4.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

There is no replacement for `user_groups`, you can´t get access to groups you don´t manage anymore.

Answer (score 1):

may i add that the reason for this message is that your application version is assigned with versoin '2.4' when you created it and you can't change that, and any call with prior version will fail,

as a work around , you may ask the user to manually enter the name of groups he has subscribed to, ask facebook for group id using its name, persist group name along with its id in backend database or file, then you can make posts to these groups using their ids,

this obviously means that your list of groups will not be synced with the groups the user liked.

Comment: Getting just the group id is not enough. The user should still grant the permission to post/access data on his behalf through user_groups permission.